# Drush site-install working with profile_name_install_tasks and forms

Tags: drush

**Is there a way to add some arguments to the drush site-install command to set the value of some form fields introduced by a hook_install_tasks() in an install profile?**

I tried some arguments variants on: `drush site-install my_profile my_profile_form.my_settings.key=value`

But to no avail.

See Drush output (for the form field 'Featureset')

`WD php: Exception: Featureset field is required. in install_run_task() (line 414 of X/includes/install.core.inc). [error]`

`WD php: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at X/drush/includes/output.inc:38) in drupal_send_headers() (line 1216 of X/includes/bootstrap.inc). [warning]`

`Exception: Featureset field is required. in install_run_task() (line 414 of X/includes/install.core.inc).`

`Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error. [error]`

Answer (score 4):

Drush `si` command has `key=value`argument.
The key is in the form `[form name].[parameter name]` on D7 or just `[parameter name]` on D6.

```
drush site-install standard install_configure_form.site_default_country=FR
```

See more: http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-6x/core/site-install